# Meaning of the notation $\int_{\mathbb R}^\oplus P(x) dx$ and $L^2(\mathbb R, H)$

Tags: functional-analysis

While reading the book "Adiabatic Perturbation Theory in Quantum Dynamics" by Teufel, I came up with the following notations:

1. $$P=\int_{\mathbb R^{3l}}^\oplus dx P_(x)$$
   I searched Wikipedia and found out that this notation is about the "direct integral". Now I know the definition of the direct integral, but **I want some introductory references that treat the direct integral in a systematic way.**
2. $$L^2(\mathbb R) \otimes H = L^2(\mathbb R, H) = \int_{\mathbb R}^\oplus dx H$$
   where $H$ is a Hilbert space. Regarding the above statement, I have the following questions:
   (1) What is the definition of $L^2(\mathbb R, H)$? I susepct that this space consists of functions $f: \mathbb R \to H$ such that $x\mapsto \langle \psi, f(x)\phi\rangle$ is measurable for all $\psi, \phi \in H$ and
   $$\int_{\mathbb R} ||f(x)||_H^2 \:dx <\infty.$$
   Is it correct?

(2) Why does the above identification valid?

Also, if there are references that deal with these matter, it would be nice to suggest a few.